Port is being added twice to Microsoft dev tunnel in VsCode with absolute URLs
I am working with the NextJs framework, where I have a link that redirect the users to it in my App. The link works well with the local machine, yet when I use the de tunnel, it adds the port twice to the URL, and it does not work.
Here is my JS code:
 function redirectToLogin(locale: string) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}/login`, hostURL)
    );
  }

Here is the result that I got from the dev tunnels:
https://k630pqpg-3000.euw.devtunnels.ms:3000/tr/login

Here is what I expect:
Either
https://k630pqpg-3000.euw.devtunnels.ms/tr/login

Or
https://k630pqpg.euw.devtunnels.ms:3000/tr/login

My workaround to solve this was to modify the URL by hand, yet it would be great to fix this bug or know a permanent solution.
Is there a way to define the URL that I got from the dev tunnels?
Note: I opened an issue related to this in the VsCode repo.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212696
